# Linked list of strings has the same strings for each node

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I'm trying to make a linked list, where each node stores a string, but I'm having a problem where each node ends up storing the same exact string in every single node. At the end of main(), I print out the word stored in each node, and it always just repeats the last string entered for the entire list.

I don't have any clue what is happening, because if I make it a string of characters it works perfectly fine, where each character is stored in the correct node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct wordnode {
    char *word;
    struct wordnode *next;
};

struct wordnode *link = NULL;

void addword(char *aword);

int main(void) {


    char *aword;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf(" %s", aword);
        addword(aword);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(; link != NULL; link = link->next) {
        printf("|%s ", link->word);
    }

    printf("|\n");
    return 0;
}

void addword(char *aword) {
    struct wordnode *cur, *prev, *new_node;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct wordnode));

    new_node->word = aword;

    for(cur = link, prev = NULL; cur != NULL; prev = cur, cur = cur->next) {
        ;
    }

    new_node->next = cur;

    if(prev == NULL) {
        link = new_node;
    } else {
        prev->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple problems. It begins with how you use `scanf` passing an uninitialized pointer. The `scanf` function needs some allocated memory big enough to write the input to. It does not allocate memory itself.

Comment: You should copy the inputed string.

Comment: A pointer does not magically create memory. `char *aword` is not initialized and points to an undefined location. Using it like that invokes Undefined Behaviour. It should be `char aword[SIZE];` in order to *allocate* a char array. And you should not simply copy pointers (`new_node->word = aword;`) but duplicate the pointed locations (see `strdup`). Finaly, it is good practice in C to consistently *free* all allocated memory. Good luck in practicing C ;-) ...

Comment: Any "working" cases that you think you have are an illusion.  You are corrupting memory, damaging your runtime environment in unpredictable ways.  This code should never be run as it is.

Comment: One problem is that you don't make a copy of each string, so you save a pointer to the array that you're going to overwrite with the next input, which isn't helpful.  Make sure you make a copy of the string — carefully.  Use `strdup()` if it is available (and it isn't hard to write your own version if it isn't available — `char *strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *copy = malloc(len); if (copy != 0) memmove(copy, str, len); return copy; }` — if you see what I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in the code. Some of them are already mentioned. The code will be something like this. Explanation at the end of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STR2(x) #x
#define STR(X) STR2(X)
#define MAXWORD 10
#define MAXWORDLEN 20

struct wordnode {
    char *word;
    struct wordnode *next;
};


struct wordnode* addword(char *aword, struct wordnode *link);
void printList(struct wordnode*link);
void freeList(struct wordnode *link);

int main(void) {
    char aword[MAXWORDLEN+1];

    struct wordnode *link = NULL;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < MAXWORD; i++) {
        if( scanf("%" STR(MAXWORDLEN) "s", aword[i]) == 1 ){
           link = addword(aword, link);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in input" );
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printList(link);  

    freeList(link);
    return 0;
}
void printList(struct wordnode*link){
    while(link){
        printf("%s \n", link->word);
        link  = link->next;
    }
}
void freeList(struct wordnode *link){
    struct wordnode *temp;
    while(link){
        temp = link;
        link = link->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

struct wordnode* addword(char *aword, struct wordnode *link) {

    struct wordnode *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct wordnode));

    if( new_node == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->word = strdup( aword );
    if( new_node->word == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in strdup" );
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if( link == NULL){
        return new_node;
    }
    struct wordnode *cur = link;
    while( cur->next != NULL ){
        cur = cur -> next;
    }
    cur->next = new_node;
    return link;
}
```

You wanted to store some string (nul terminated char array) and then you wanted to add them in the list. Also from your example implementation you were trying to add it in the list at the tail.

To sum up -

- `scanf` demands a pointer to some memory where it can store inputted data. But yours were uninitialized.
- secondly the way you were copying strings, it was just a shallow copy (you were making it point to some already existing memory). You need copy it either using `strdup` or `malloc - memcpy` or `malloc-strcpy`.
- In case POSIX `strdup()` is not available, you can use what Jonathan Leffler mentioned.
- Here you can see that we have freed the allocated memory using `freeList()` function. *When you are done working with the memory you allocated- free the memory.*
- Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.
- Also check whether the `malloc` is successful checking it's return value.
- You have used the list head as the global variable. It is not needed here.

Comment: thanks but I cannot use strdup, I'm working with ISO C.

But I made the struct have a character to an array of a certain size so it's initialized, instead of a pointer, and then called scanf to put the string directly into that array of each node after calling malloc, which seems to be working out just fine, which eliminates the aword variable entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`char * aword` is not initialized and located. It should be:

```
char aword[100];
```

(100 is just a number, size of array. You can replace it with any number what you want)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments this is not the only problem, please improve your answer.

Comment: this answer very useful to me, because it was short and simple. It led me to figuring out other problems.

I thought scanf allocated memory into a string automatically, so that's why I hadn't initialized aword.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated memory for the string. As a result `aword` would contain garbage value and passing this to `scanf` is a undefined behavior. Lets say `aword` has `0x7fffe4e0cdf0` and your `scanf` stores the string at the address `0x7fffe4e0cdf0` and pass this address to the `addword` function and your structure member `word` is also updated with the same value. The next scanf also stores the new value in the same memory pointed by `aword` and passes to the function. As a result `word` in all the linked lists are pointing to the same memory location. The ideal solution is to allocate memory for each string being scanned and pass it to the '`addword' function.