# Unnecessary Changes being made when appending to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

A I have managed to get the linked list to function in the sense that it can create a list store variables in them, but now I have run into another issue that I've never been able find the solution to. Any time I run it through a list of variables I want stored it will run through the list and create the right number of nodes, but the string variable keeps getting changed after each append. 
For example if I run:

```
"Dog" "cat" "house"
```

Instead of the desired output:

```
Dog
cat
house
```

It produces

```
house
house
house
```

I'm unsure why it keeps doing it and I can't seem to pin where the head node string is being altered except for the first instance in which the list is empty and thus needs to assign a new head.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


#define EMPTY NULL;

typedef struct listnode{
  struct listnode* next;
  char* fileName;
} listnode;

struct listnode* head;

//This section of code will be dedicated to the creation and management
//of the listnode functions

listnode* createNode(char* str, listnode* next){
  listnode* tempo;
  tempo = (listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));

  if(tempo == NULL){
    printf("Error creating space for new node.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  tempo->fileName = str;
  tempo->next = next;

  return tempo;
}

listnode* append(listnode* head, char* str){
  listnode* temp;
  listnode* curr;

  temp = createNode(str, NULL);

  if(head == NULL){
    head = temp;
    return head;
  }
  else{
    curr = head;
    while(curr->next != NULL){
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = temp;
    return head;
  }
}

void printNames(listnode* head){
  listnode* curr= head;

  while(curr !=NULL){
    printf("%s \n", curr->fileName);
    curr = curr->next;
  }
}

void list_free(listnode* head){
  listnode* current;
  listnode* temp;

  if(head != NULL){
    current = head->next;

    if(head !=NULL){
      current = head -> next;
      head ->next = NULL;
      while(current != NULL){
    temp = current -> next;
    free(current);
    current = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  free(head);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *current_dir = NULL;
  DIR *direct_ptr = NULL;
  struct dirent *dir_ptr = NULL;
  unsigned int fileNum = 0;
  int c;
  listnode* head = NULL;

  current_dir = getenv("PWD");
  if(NULL == current_dir){
    printf("\n Error: Couldn't grab current directory.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  direct_ptr = opendir((const char*)current_dir);
  if(NULL == direct_ptr){
    printf("\n Error: couldn't open current directory\n");
    return -1;
  }


  for(fileNum=0; NULL != (dir_ptr = readdir(direct_ptr)); fileNum++){
    if(dir_ptr->d_name[0] != '.'){
      head = append(head, dir_ptr->d_name);
    }
  }
  printNames(head);
}
```

Comment: The usual reason for this, is because you are storing a pointer to the same buffer in every node, but the buffer contains just the latest string. Instead of `tempo->fileName = str;` try `tempo->fileName = strdup(str);` if your compiler supports `strdup()`. If not, you can `malloc()` sufficient memory (`strlen(fileName) + 1`) and `strcpy()` the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linked list of strings has the same strings for each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863608/linked-list-of-strings-has-the-same-strings-for-each-node).

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays (such as strings) are not passed by value. They are instead passed by pointer. When you specify the a char array as a function parameter, the array [decays to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Therefore, you must either

1. ensure that the string that the listnode struct member `filename` points to remains valid and is not overwritten, or
2. store a copy of the string in the listnode struct.

In order to copy a string, you can use the function [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). However, you must then either allocate enough space for the char array in the listnode struct or you must use dynamic memory allocation (such as `malloc`) and store a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory.